# "Comments only" lock notice on closed questions mistakenly says that question is still accepting answers

Tags: bug, closed-questions, locked-questions, post-notices

When a question has a "comments-only" lock, the following notice is displayed on top of the question:

> **Locked for X days**. Comments on this question have been disabled, but it *is still accepting new answers* and other interactions.

However, I noticed that if the question is closed (even before the lock), the same notice is used:

[image: "comments-only" locks' notice on closed questions]

..which could be confusing, especially for new users.

**Proposed change to the notice *on closed questions*:**

> **Locked for X days**. Comments on this question have been disabled, but it is still accepting [votes and] other interactions.

Or, as others have suggested, the additional *"but it is still accepting [...]"* part can simply be removed as it hardly provides any new information.

Comment: Heck, you could even do away with the "but..." part. Simply say "Comments on this question have been disabled." Short, sweet, to the point, and only shown on closed AND locked questions... A rather rare combination.

Comment: I thought it was fine as a feature request - we’re requesting that the text be changed  so it doesn’t conflict with the wording of other posts. It’s not really something that’s broken.

Comment: @ColleenV The way I look at it now is that SE didn't intend to have the notice say that the question is accepting answers when it's not. It's just an edge case that was overlooked. I say that's a bug.

Comment: I can see it that way too. I was mostly just responding to the  comment describing your edit.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another example of how confusing this is in juxtaposition.

[image: Screenshot of an off-topic notice and a comment lock notice]

The closed notice says “It is not accepting answers” and the comment lock notice says “but it is still accepting new answers”.

I think it would be better to focus post notices on their purpose. “Comments disabled for *time period*.” and then include something about the purpose of a comment lock instead of making assertions about other aspects of the post that may not be true or relevant.

Comment: If nothing else, "Locked" should go on top.