# Contradictory messages when question is closed and comments disabled

Tags: bug, closed-questions, comment-lock

I spotted this on Super User but I believe the same or similar messages can appear on any SE site. Below are two messages that contradict each other. They appeared in a single post, one under the other:

> [image: screenshot of two contradictory messages]

<sup>(For the record, the screenshot is from [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1610586/432690).)</sup>

The first message states [emphasis mine]:

> Closed. **This question […] is not currently accepting answers**.

The second message states [again, emphasis mine]:

> Locked […]. Comments on this question have been disabled, **but it is still accepting new answers** and other interactions.

The question at the time was not accepting new answers. The first message was right, the second message was wrong in this matter. The second message should be corrected. It should reflect the actual status of the question. It should not contradict with the first message.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22accepting+new+answers%22) of ["Comments only" lock notice on closed questions mistakenly says that question is still accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351422/289905).